# integral representation for $\sum_{k=0}^{x}k^{p}$

Tags: definite-integrals, summation, stirling-numbers, bernoulli-polynomials

How the following integral representation can be derived?
$$\sum_{k=0}^{x}k^{p}=\int_{0}^{x+1}B_{p}\left(t\right)dt=\frac{B_{p+1}\left(x+1\right)-B_{p+1}}{p+1}$$

I know Faulhaber's formula which is as follows:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{x}k^{p}=\frac{1}{p+1}\sum_{j=0}^{p}B_{j}{{p+1}\choose{j}}\left(N\right)^{\left(p+1-j\right)}$$

where $N=x+1$

or another formula:
$$\sum_{p=1}^{k}p^{n}=\sum_{m=1}^{p}{{k+1}\choose{m+1}}{n\brace m}m!$$

but I don't know if they are useful or not.

Comment: In Faulhaber's formula the variable $x$ is used with two different meanings in the same scope. The right-hand side has $N=x+1$ in use as well as the index $x$. This is not admissible.

Answer (score 4):

We use the generating function
\begin{align*}
\frac{te^{tx}}{e^t-1}=\sum_{n\geq 0}B_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
of *[Bernoulli polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Generating_functions)* to derive the integral representation.

> From (1) we can show for $n\geq 1$
>   \begin{align*}
> B_{n}(x+1)-B_n(x)&=nx^{n-1}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>   as follows:

We obtain
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(B_n(x+1)-B_n(x)\right)\frac{t^n}{n!}
&=\frac{te^{t(x+1)}}{e^t-1}-\frac{te^{tx}}{e^t-1}\tag{3}\\
&=\frac{te^{tx}e^t}{e^t-1}-\frac{te^{tx}}{e^t-1}\\
&=te^{tx}\\
&=t\sum_{n\geq 0}x^n\frac{t^n}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n\geq 1}nx^{n-1}\frac{t^n}{n!}\tag{4}
\end{align*}

Comparison of the coefficient of $t^p$ in (3) and (4) gives for $p\geq 1$:
\begin{align*}
B_{p}(x+1)-B_p(x)=px^{p-1}
\end{align*}
and the claim (2) follows. Division by $p$ and shifting $p$ by one gives
\begin{align*}
x^p=\frac{B_{p+1}(x+1)-B_{p+1}(x)}{p+1}\tag{5}
\end{align*}

> We obtain from (5) for $N\geq 0, p\geq 0$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^Nk^p}&=\sum_{k=0}^N\frac{B_{p+1}(k+1)-B_{p+1}(k)}{p+1}\\
> &=\frac{B_{p+1}(N+1)-B_{p+1}(0)}{p+1}\tag{6}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{B_{p+1}(N+1)-B_{p+1}}{p+1}}\tag{7}\\
> \end{align*}

In (6) and (7) we use the telescoping property and $B_p(0)=B_p, p\geq 0$.

> We obtain from (1)
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n\geq 0}B_n^{\prime}(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{te^{tx}}{e^t-1}\right)\tag{8}\\
> &=\frac{t^2e^{tx}}{e^t-1}\\
> &=\sum_{n\geq 0}^{\infty}B_n(x)\frac{t^{n+1}}{n!}\tag{9}
> \end{align*}

In the following we use the *coefficient of* operator $[t^p]$ to denote the coeffficient of $t^p$ in a series. Coefficient comparison of $t^p$ in  (8) and (9) gives for $p\geq 1$:
\begin{align*}
p![t^p]\sum_{n\geq 0}B_n^{\prime}(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}&=B_p^{\prime}(x)\tag{10}\\
p![t^p]\sum_{n\geq 0}B_n(x)\frac{t^{n+1}}{n!}&=p!B_{p-1}(x)\frac{1}{(p-1)!}\\
&=pB_{p-1}(x)\tag{11}
\end{align*}

> We obtain from (10) and (11)
>   \begin{align*}
> \int_{0}^{x+1}B_{p+1}^{\prime}(u)du&=B_{p+1}(x+1)-B_{p+1}(0)\\
> &=(p+1)\int_{0}^{x+1}B_{p}(u)du\\
> \end{align*}
>   from which
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\int_{0}^{x+1}B_{p}(u)du=\frac{B_{p+1}(x+1)-B_{p+1}}{p+1}}
> \end{align*}
>   follows.

Comment: First of all thank you for your consideration, but can you explain what is the notation $p!\left[t^{p}\right]$? also why did you multiply $p!\left[t^{p}\right]$ by $$\sum_{n\ge0}^{ }B_{n}^{'}\left(x\right)\cdot\frac{t^{n}}{n!}$$? I actually cannot understand line 10 and 11

Comment: @user715522: You're welcome. $[t^p]$ denotes the coefficient of $t^p$ in a series. I've added this info in my answer. Since the coefficient of $[t^p]$ in line (10) is $B_p^{\prime}(x)/p!$ we multiply by $p!$ to get $B_p^{\prime}(x)$ without any additional factors.

Comment: can you explain how  from \begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{x+1}B_{p+1}^{\prime}(u)du&=B_{p+1}(x+1)-B_{p+1}(0)\\
&
\end{align*} you get \begin{align*}(p+1)\int_{0}^{x+1}B_{p}(u)du\\\end{align*}

Comment: @user715522: We know from (10) and (11) that $B_p^{\prime}(x)=pB_{p-1}(x)$. We then substitute $p$ with $p+1$ and integrate from $0$ to $x+1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, here we have $$B_{p+1}\left(x+1\right)=\frac{B'_{p+2}\left(x\right)}{p+2}$$ so $$B_{p+1}\left(x+1\right)-B_{p+1}\left(0\right)=\frac{B'_{p+2}\left(x\right)-B'_{p+2}\left(0\right)}{p+2}$$, I just do't get where does the integral come from

Comment: @user715522: Since $B_p^{\prime}(u)$ are  polynomials  in   $u$  they are  integrable. So,  we can integrate them to  obtain $\int_{0}^{x+1}B_p^{\prime}(u)\,du=B_p(x+1)-B_p(0)$.